# How to extract email address from string using NSRegularExpression

Tags: iphone, ios, regex

I am making an iphone application. I have a scenario where i have a huge string, which has lot of data, and i would like to extract only email addresses from the string.

For example if the string is like

> asdjasjkdh asdhajksdh jkashd sample@email.com asdha jksdh asjdhjak sdkajs test@gmail.com

i should extract "sample@email.com" and "test@gmail.com"

and i also want to extract only date, from the string

For example if the string is like

> asdjasjkdh  01/01/2012 asdhajksdh jkas 12/11/2012 hd sample@email.com asdha jksdh asjdhjak sdkajs test@gmail.com

i should extract "01/01/2012" and "12/11/2012"

A small code snipet, will be very helpful.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This will do what you want:

```
// regex string for emails (feel free to use a different one if you prefer)
NSString *regexString = @"([A-Za-z0-9_\\-\\.\\+])+\\@([A-Za-z0-9_\\-\\.])+\\.([A-Za-z]+)";

// experimental search string containing emails
NSString *searchString = @"asdjasjkdh 01/01/2012 asdhajksdh jkas 12/11/2012 hd sample@email.com asdha jksdh asjdhjak sdkajs test@gmail.com";

// track regex error
NSError *error = NULL;

// create regular expression
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:regexString options:0 error:&error];

// make sure there is no error
if (!error) {

    // get all matches for regex
    NSArray *matches = [regex matchesInString:searchString options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, searchString.length)];

    // loop through regex matches
    for (NSTextCheckingResult *match in matches) {

        // get the current text
        NSString *matchText = [searchString substringWithRange:match.range];

        NSLog(@"Extracted: %@", matchText);

    }

}
```

Using your sample string above:

> asdjasjkdh 01/01/2012 asdhajksdh jkas 12/11/2012 hd sample@email.com asdha jksdh asjdhjak sdkajs test@gmail.com

The output is:

```
Extracted: sample@email.com
Extracted: test@gmail.com
```

To use the code, just set `searchString` to the string you want to search. Instead of the NSLog() methods, you'll probably want to do something with the extracted strings `matchText`. Feel free to use a different regex string to extract emails, just replace the value of `regexString` in the code.

Comment: Needless to say, use a date regex if you're looking to extract dates!

Answer (score 1):

```
NSArray *chunks = [mylongstring componentsSeparatedByString: @" "];

for(int i=0;i<[chunks count];i++){
    NSRange aRange = [chunks[i] rangeOfString:@"@"];
    if (aRange.location !=NSNotFound) NSLog(@"email %@",chunks[i] );
}
```

Comment: This code breaks the text by spaces, loops through each chunk looking for the `@` symbol. I would suggest using regex to identify emails because it will be much more accurate.

Comment: On the contrary, this is a great way to **avoid** regex when it's not necessary and may unnecessarily complicate things.

Comment: Yes, but I disagree that it is unnecessary here. It's possible to encounter other uses of `@` in text (such as references to handles on sites, image file names like Apple's @2x, etc.) in addition to malformed email addresses. Regex performs accurate validation and lookup :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex to match emails

```
 [^\s]*@[^\s]*
```

and this regex to match dates

```
 \d+/\d+/\d+
```

Comment: @syedimty i dnt know about `ios` but u should use method like `match` if it exists..not sure about that

Comment: Thanks for reply, will try and let you know